# Undefined reference to 'AbstractClass::getInfo'

Tags: c++, abstract-class, undefined-reference

I have `AbstractClass` and `virtual int getInfo() = 0;` plus `static int info;`
And I have class `ConcreteClass` with

```
int ConcreteClass::getInfo()
{
    return info;
}
```

But I get errors

```
Undefined reference to 'AbstractClass::getInfo'
```

and

```
collect2:error:ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please tell me what the problem with this is.

Update: Should I define my `int info` in the `AbstractClass` constructor?

Comment: Could you show the whole definition of `AbstractClass` and `ConcreteClass`, as well as how you are using them?

Comment: Have you defined the static int `info` in source file?

Comment: Let me guess (because there is little info), did you forget to add keyword public to the Concrete class declaration?: ConcreteClass:: public AbstractClass